# Read wrong values from binary file

Tags: c, arrays, struct, binaryfiles

I want to take an array of structs so I can sort it by name and write it on a txt file. But it takes wrong values like strange symbols or numbers. Anyone knows what is wrong?

```
typedef struct candidato Candidato;

struct candidato {
    char inscr[10];
    char nome[44];
    int periodo;
    int posicao;
    char curso[30];
};

FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
    return ;
}
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t sz = ftell(fp);
int ncand = sz/sizeof(Candidato);
rewind(fp);
Candidato *arr = malloc(sz);
if (arr == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes memory\n", sz);
    return ;
}
printf("%d \n",ncand);
int i;
int cont;
for (i = 0; fread(&arr[i], sizeof(Candidato), 1, fp) == 1; i++){
    printf("%s\n",arr[i].nome); //test if it got what I want
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `Candidato`.

Comment: Give an example of the "wrong values" and what they should be.

Comment: Definition and values examples posted

Comment: is your file correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and here's the working code:

```
FILE *f = fopen (filename, "rb");
if(f==NULL){
    printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo. \n");
    system("pause");
    return;
}
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
int  sz = ftell(f);
rewind(f);
Candidato arr[sz/sizeof(Candidato)];
int i;
for (i = 0; fread(&arr[i], sizeof(Candidato), 1, f) == 1; i++) {
    printf("%s %i \n",arr[i].nome,arr[i].inscr);
}
```